# How to Manipulate a ListLinePlot[Transpose[{T,B}]] if T is a Table and B is a list of minima built by using FindMinimum?

Tags: manipulate

I need to Manipulate a ListLinePlot using a parameter P. The problem is that this Curve is a ListLinePlot of a Transpose[{T,B}], in which T is a normal table and B is a list of minima got using FindMinimum in f[x]. This is a simplified code that contains my concern:

```
f[x_] := (b/a)*x^2 + (x^2/b)
Quiet[Xmin = Table[
   FindMinimum[{f[x], a >= 1, b >= 1}, {a, b}], {x, 250, 310, 20}]];

T = Table[T, {T, 250, 310, 20}];
B = b /. Take[Xmin, All, {2}] // Flatten;
Transpose[{T, B}];

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{T, B}]]
```

I'm able to plot this ListLinePlot as it is presented in the code but the idea is to insert a parameter P, multiplying the constant "a", inside of f[x] (P varies from 1 - 50).

When I just put this ListLinePlot correctly inside the Manipulate expression, setting P as a changeable parameter and also insert the parameter P, multiplying the constant "a", the routine is not able to output B and I get a list of errors. I really need B, so, is there any way to Manipulate it?

The Manipulate code that is not working is this:

```
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[Transpose[{T, B}]], {P, 1, 50}]
```

But with this Manipulate code above is evaluated only if I change "a" for "a*P" in the f[x].

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please include the `Manipulate` code you are trying.

Comment: I get `FindMinimum::eit: The algorithm does not converge ..`. Don't you?

Comment: If `P` multiplies just `a`, introducing the new parm will result in a new `a`.... which is the old one just divided by `P` ....

Comment: @Öskå, Yes it gives an error message but in the end the ListLinePlot is accomplished.

Comment: One usually doesn't like error messages.. :)

Comment: @Roberto Please add a `Quiet` to `FindMinimum` and your `Manipulate[..]` in your question :)

Comment: @belisarius, the idea is not only change "a" for "P*a", the main idea is to be able to Manipulate the plot output in terms of P.

Comment: @Öskå, I have already done modifications.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Manipulate code included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very slow to update due to the repetitive use of `FindMinimum` but perhaps it is what you want:

```
DynamicModule[{f, Xmin, T, B, a, b},
 Manipulate[
  f[x_] := (b/(a*P))*x^2 + (x^2/b);
  Xmin = Quiet@Table[FindMinimum[{f[x], a >= 1, b >= 1}, {a, b}], {x, 250, 310, 20}];
  T = Range[250, 310, 20];
  B = b /. Take[Xmin, All, {2}] // Flatten;
  ListLinePlot[Transpose[{T, B}]],
  {P, 1, 50, 1},
  TrackedSymbols :> {P}
 ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much! It was a really small version of my code. I have encapsulated everything in one manipulate but it is taking ages to evaluate. It works but it takes ages. Thanks again!